# How to store Power BI session data without Localstorage?

Tags: typescript, session-cookies, session-variables, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am developing a custom Power BI visual. In my use case, the visual need to authenticate the users to a third party server with the Oauth2 protocol. When opening the report, every user should have a separate access token connected to this account. So, basically, my need is to save some user specific browser session data.

I know there is the Localstorage API and I am considering this for the future, but the certification and publication path is not something doable right now.

I also tried to use cookies and the typescript built-in sessionstorage object, but none of them work. Also, saving authentication credentials in another server to retrieve them later is not an option, other than ugly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Power bi service has its own security settings to control the operations, so you can't directly export session to local from visual without use local storage API.

 

Refer to this Microsoft Learn documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-power-bi-security#data-storage-security